# rm command not ask before delete

Tags: vps, virtual-machines, xen, centos5

i have centos VPS created using XEN + OpenVZ virtualization.

```
-bash-3.2# uname -a
Linux host.domain.com 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5.028stab095.1xen #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 22:10:04 MSD 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

there are no question asked when i want to delete file(s)

```
-bash-3.2# vi test.txt
-bash-3.2# rm test.txt
-bash-3.2#
```

the main server (not virtualized one) is asking me first before delete any files.

```
[root@main ~]# vi test.txt
[root@main ~]# rm test.txt
rm: remove regular file `test.txt'? y
[root@main ~]#
```

how to configure virtualized environment to prompt me before deleting any file(s)?

thank you.

**UPDATES:** i don't want to use rm -i for each rm command. bashrc selected as answer.

**FIXED:**

i'm copying `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` from main server

i) `#vi .bashrc`

enter the following:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

ii) copy default bash profile into user path

> cp /etc/skel/.bash_profile /root/

ref: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=50751

now my shell become `[root@servername ~]#`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default CentOS .bashrc has the following in it:

```
# cat .bashrc
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
```

In your example, your prompt looks like `-bash-3.2#`.  This suggests that .bashrc is missing, or you became root without taking on the root's environment properly.

Comment: thank you, clear explaination. now i'm searching about bashrc

Comment: problem fixed. see updates dan fix.

Answer (score 6):

Use "rm -i".

You can use bash aliases. Just append

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

to you ~/.bashrc and run

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prompt before deleting files or directories. You will need to use

```
rm -i
```

If you also want to have a prompt for directories

```
rm -ri
```

You can add this to your .bashrc as per example by Dmitry.